# TFS delete - The item XXX already has pending changes. No arguments matched any files to delete. How to delete a item?

Tags: tfs

I am trying to delete a file from TFS.

So I am running the following commands in this sequence -

tfs get ....
tfs checkout ....
tfs get ....
tfs delete  ....(failed at this point)
tfs checkin  ......

While running this command the tfs delete fails with this error

***The item XXX already has pending changes. 
No arguments matched any files to delete.***

I can't understand what am i doing wrong? Is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 7):

Who has the pending change on the file? You? If so then just `undo changes` on it then delete it.

If you are not the one with the pending change then you will need to get a TFS admin to do the undo changes operation for you.

Alternatively if you are doing this from the command line and have sufficient privileges then use the `/force` switch.

Comment: Well, this is whats confusing me. I just did a checkout  and no one (including me) have changed anything on this file. So i am pretty sure there are no pending changes.  I will try the "/force" options... thanks !

Comment: @user1752021 You do not need to checkout a file to delete it.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and ran `tf undo FULLFILEPATH` and then `tf delete FULLFILEPATH`. It was deleted shortly after. Like @slugster said, if you don't own the changes you will have to get an admin to do it for you.